# Lodash mixin not working in JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, mixins

I was chaining my custom functions using lodash's `_.mixin` or `_.chain`. The code was working fine when it was outside of a class as below:

Working code:

```
     function start(data, param1, param2) {
      _.mixin({
        'someFunc': this.someFunc,
        'anotherFunc': this.anotherFunc
      })

      // Chaining directly works
      _.someFunc(data, param1)
       .anotherFunc(param2)

     // Using chain works
     return _.chain(data)
      .someFunc(param1)
      .anotherFunc(param2)
     }

     function someFunc(data, param) {
       return data;
     }

     function anotherFunc(data, param) {
       return data + param;
     }
```

The moment I used the code in a class, it started throwing a `TypeError: _.chain(...).someFunc is not a function`

```
  import * as _ from 'lodash';

  class MyClass {
    constructor() {
      //.... code
    }

    start(data, param1, param2) {

      // Does not work
      _.mixin({
         'someFunc': this.someFunc,
         'anotherFunc': this.anotherFunc
      })

      // Does not work
      _.someFunc(data, param1)
       .anotherFunc(param2)

      // Also does not work
      return _.chain(data)
       .someFunc(param1)
       .anotherFunc(param2)

     // Using them separately works:
     let result = _.someFunc(param1);
     let result2 = _.anotherFunc(param2);

    }

    someFunc(data, param) {
      return data;
    }

    anotherFunc(data, param) {
      return data + param;
    }


  }
```

If anyone can shed insight on why this is happening, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
_.someFunc(data, param1)
 .anotherFunc(param2)
```

`someFunc` does not return an lodash wrapper object, so you can't call `anotherFunc` on the return value.

Comment: What about       ```return _.chain(data).someFunc(param1).anotherFunc(param2).value()``` Isn't the chain method supposed to chain custom functions? And why would this work outside of a class but not inside?

Comment: Yes, chain does chain custom functions. The `return ...` line works fine for me, could you provide more information on your error? What version lodash are you running?

Comment: Lodash 4.17.2. I'm using it with webpack/angular. Yeah, the chain method works for me outside of classes. When use inside of a class, it breaks.

Comment: Strange. Apart from what's given in this answer, both of your examples run without error for me. Maybe `_.chain` was overwritten perhaps? What does `_.chain(data).value()` return?

Comment: Very strange. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. `_.chain(data).value()` returns `undefined` but only inside of a class.